# How to handle bounties when you have non-useful answers to choose from?

Tags: support, bounty

I put a bounty on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631983/fluent-nhibernate-use-the-same-mapping-files-for-tables-with-the-same-structure). Then, after a few days, I found the solution by myself, and posted it as an answer.

Now I see that someone else posted an answer which seems to be a shorter (and not very helpful) version of my answer.

What will happen with my bounty?

As I can't award it to myself, should I wait until someone comes with a better description?

Comment: If an answer is not useful, downvote it.  Unfortunately, you don't have the rep to do so.  If you feel it was plagiarized from your answer, flag it, and moderators can take a look to see if it's worthy of deletion.

Comment: ok, thanks...then I wait until someone gives an anser which has more value than my own...

Comment: @Gener4tor I am really sorry about this situation I actually did not notice your answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If no eligible answer is posted and you do not award it manually; the bounty is lost.

You are not in any way obliged to award it if you do not feel any of the posted answers deserve it.

In this case, the bounty period has ended, and so has the grace period. So the bounty amount will be lost.

For more information, [here you have the help center page for bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Better luck next time!

Comment: Given that the asker considers that other answer a basically lower quality version of their own, I'd say they lucked out on this one (unless the meta effect plays out in the stupidest way possible, or someone pulls a sock puppet on their answer). But this is a matter of perspective, after all, so one's mileage may vary.

Comment: I meant _“better luck next time getting quality answers for your bounty“_. But otherwise I agree with you, @Bolt.

Comment: The help page says, if no action is taken, *The highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount... If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.* What if there's an answer with a score of 2+ which isn't helpful at all, is there an button for "Don't award bounty to anyone"? Otherwise, it sounds like it'll be awarded by default, which is undesirable for an insufficient answer.

Comment: @nkr Bounties are non-refundable, under any circumstances, period. It's not that I might want a refund (since that's impossible anyway), it's that none of the answers might deserve the bounty if they don't solve the problem, so I'm wondering what to do in that sort of situation.

Comment: @Snow: You can downvote the answer and hope it stays under 2 score. Other than that there's basically nothing a bountier can do to prevent a debatably good answer from getting the auto-award. This is at least 50% by design; auto-award is designed to cover for lazy, ignorant, or abusive bounty-setters by ensuring that if the community as a whole likes an answer it can still get the bounty even if the setter is unwilling to recognize it as suitable.

Comment: @Snow Bounties can be refunded actually, by moderators, this happened to me once when the question i put a bounty on was later marked as a duplicate during the bounty period

Comment: @Snow We generally trust the user community not to upvote unhelpful answers.

Comment: @Chris_Rands flagging a question for being dupe isn't possible anymore during the bounty period. I often see such questions, but there is little to do about it, except manually leaving a comment (which people most likely use as source for their "own" answers then).

Comment: @MartinZeitler it is possible for moderators!

Comment: @Chris_Rands didn't know that, now I do. makes sense in combination with what yivi wrote.

Answer (score 14):

### The copied answer

To address the issue of the copied less detailed version of your answer. I just deleted it and left a comment.

> This is, essentially, a copy of another answer. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

In future raise a custom mod flag if someone copies your work. Include a link to the copied post. We'll delete the post (if it is copied).

### The bounty

There's nothing that can be done if no other answers are posted.

The bounty system is a risk. Looks like you more than made up for the bounty rep posted by the attention drawn to the post and answer by the bounty and this meta post. That's all we can hope for. Enough attention to get answers and regain rep.

Although it's frustrating to "waste" rep, when you found your own answer, it's always better to find that answer and just count the loss as water under the bridge (if the rep isn't made back).

The bounty rep is lost, whether it is awarded to another user or not.

Comment: once had similar issue while the result was receiving a notice via email, complaining that "rudeness was detected" on my profile; then I went above and beyond to provide the perfect answer and still received the bounty... at least I know now what to do if this should happen again. while in my case it wasn't that obvious, because it had been rewritten and watered down, something alike the "simple language" version of it; but the revision log still showed it had been copied.